# User calling a method throughout any period of the program

Tags: java, loops, methods

I'm trying to build a text based D&D type game, and I'm stuck on how to let the user call a method at any time during the game.

The game will run its course, and if the user decides at any time they want to take a peak at his/her stats, the user will type "character sheet" and all his stats etc. will show.

My only idea to go about my problem is to to use:

```
if( variable.equals("character sheet"))
       callMethod();
```

but this only works once.

Now even if I put it in a loop, yes, it would let me do it as many times as I want, but it won't execute the rest of the program...

Without the loop it will let me do it once, and execute the rest of the program but will never let the user type Character Sheet and open the method ever again.
/////////////////

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainGame
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String characterSheet;


    CharacterCreation create = new CharacterCreation();
    System.out.println("Choose a race:");
    System.out.println("Race List:\nDwarf\nDark Elf\nHalfling\nHuman");
    create.stats();
    System.out.println("If you want to see your character sheet in the future type 'character sheet'");
    characterSheet = input.nextLine();
    characterSheet.toLowerCase();

     if(characterSheet.equals("Character Sheet"))
           create.getStats();


}
```

}

Comment: We can't really know what's wrong without seeing the code where user input is read

Comment: What is the "rest of the program"? Is it round-based? So you always expect user input?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the big question is: is your game running whatever the user does, or does it run in step with each user action? In the second case, you need a simple loop:

```
while (isRunning){
  getUserInput();
  updateGameWorld();
}
```

If the game runs independently of the user's action, you'll need 2 threads: one that will update the world regularly, and one that will listen to the user inputs and adapt the world to them.

I'd suggest you read about "game loops", but be warned that they usually about drawing graphics in frame, which may dilute their general purpose. But basically you have one game loop that renders the world, and another thread that handles user actions.